# Postpone Jenkins plugin update before restart

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I asked to update one of the plugins, it was downloaded successfully. And it says it will be activated during next boot.

But I do not want to update this plugin anymore, is there a way to cancel this update request?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the reboot and then go back into the plugin management page and downgrade back to your prior version.